# Instancing classes from dynamically loaded modules

Tags: python-3.5

What is the best way to load classes from python source code files on disk, dynamically? (Meaning I cannot just `import className`)

So far, I was able to load the source code into memory and make a python module object out of it using the following:

```
spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location(modname, sourcepath)
module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
```

So far, the code works. What I did next is use the inspect.getmembers() function to extract only classes from the loaded module, but, and this is the issue, the function returns an empty list.

```
classes = inspect.getmembers(module, inspect.isclass)
```

This code actually worked in Python 2, where the only difference was that I loaded the source file into a module form using the `imp` library and the `imp.load_source(modname, modpath))` function.

What I need this code is for the `inspect.getmembers` call to return a list of classes of the specific module, or, to implement this dynamic class lookup in another way.

The reason I'm doing this is that I'm writing a small program that loads plugins, in the form of python classes, that it then interfaces with using predefined function calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of messing around, I found that the solution was pretty simple.

I only had to change the way the module gets loaded into a spec like so:

```
loader = importlib.machinery.SourceFileLoader(filename, dirpath+"/"+filename)
spec = importlib.util.spec_from_loader(loader.name, loader)
module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
loader.exec_module(module)
```

This approached lead to the `inspect.getmembers` to return valid classes from the module.